# Generating groups of skewed size but whose elements add to a fixed sum

Tags: r, random, sampling

I have some fixed number of people (e.g. 1000). I would like to split these 1000 people into some random number of classes Y (e.g. 5), but not equally. I want them to be distributed unevenly, according to some probability distribution that is heavily skewed (something like a power-law distribution).

My intuition is that I need to generate a distribution of probabilities that is (1) skewed and (2) which also adds up to 1.

My ad hoc solution was to generate random numbers from a power law distribution, multiply these by some scalar that ensures these add up to something close to my target number, adjust my target number to that new number, and then split accordingly.

But it seems awfully inelegant, and 'y_size' doesn't always sum to 1000, which requires looping through and trying again. What's a better approach?

```
require(poweRlaw)
x<-1000
y<-10
y_sizes<-rpldis(10,xmin=5,alpha=2,discrete_max=x)
y_sizes<-round(y_sizes * x/sum(y_sizes)) 
newx<-y_sizes #newx only approx = x rather than = x
people<-1:x
groups<-cut(
  people,
  c(0,cumsum(y_sizes))
) %>% as.numeric
data.frame(
  people=people,
  group=groups
)
```

Comment: Could use `rep` to split them in to groups e.g. `out <- rep(1:y, y_sizes)`. One thing I notice is that `length(y_sizes)` doesn't always equal 1000 due to the roundings, so you will need to add a catch for this e.g. if its 999, or 1001 etc.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I should have clarified - b/c of the rounding, I don't always end up w/ a 1000, which is what I'd like to avoid. Your solution makes sense and that's what I've implemented, but anything more elegant (i.e. ,which doesn't require looping back through to try again)?

Comment: I guess you could use `sample` to sample 1000 draws of `1:y` with replacement as TRUE using `y_sizes/sum(y_sizes)` as the probabilities. Can use `set.seed` function for reproducibility. Otherwise use `ceiling` for `y_sizes` instead and then sample without replacement. If you use ceiling instead of  `round` you will be guaranteed to have at least 1000 values so can then just randomly decide which 1000 to keep with sample

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm presented by Smith and Tromble in "[Sampling Uniformly from the Unit Simplex](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Enasmith/papers/smith+tromble.tr04.pdf)" shows a solution.  I have pseudocode on this algorithm in my section "[Random Integers with a Given Positive Sum](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Random_Integers_with_a_Given_Positive_Sum)".